# In Vuejs, dynamically inline css based on User Agent

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

How do I import css differently based on user agent

Current Code

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import '../styles/sample.scss';
</style>
<template>
<h1 >Hello Big font</h1>
</template>
```

Need code to either load sample.scss or mobile_sample.scss based on variable which specifies if the UA is of a mobile
Note: Already have the logic for parsing the UA need to know how to dynamically import a files

Comment: Importing stuff works at build-time, not at run-time. At build-time you have no information about the client. So no, this will not work.

Comment: What might solve your problem is limiting your stylesheet `link` element using media queries. `<link href=/link/to/your/css.css media="screen and (max-width: 639px)" />`

Comment: yeah, I get that but is there not a way to dynamically load things like we can load import components dynamically ex: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/any-way-to-dynamically-add-multiple-vue-components-within-a-parent-vue-component/8209/2

Comment: @AbhayKumar It is simply not possible - .vue files (and the `<style>` tags within) are processed during the build step and at that point you have zero information on your users UA.

Comment: ok, I was just wondering if there ware ways to get around it